# Looking for an old short story about an ultra smart boy with an alien/robot babysitter

Tags: story-identification, aliens, robots

I am looking for a short story about a young problematic ultra smart boy, with fighting parents, that gets a robot/alien babysitter/guardian.

Comment: When did you read this, was it a long story or short story in an anthology?

Comment: The description is rather short, I can think of a South Park episode that fit exactly this description. Care to elaborate ? Also welcome to Scifi&Fantasy SE.

Comment: yeah it was in an old anthology. I remember the boy was genetically modified to be very smart and pretty and was behaving badly - and his parents were forced to take on this creature, i also remember the creature taught the boy discipline and to pity his kind of narcissistic parents

Comment: Your description is too skimpy. Please tell us ***everything*** you can remember about the story and the book you read it in. How old was the boy? 19 years? 2 years? How was he behaving badly? Was he running red lights, setting cats on fire, highlighting books, walking through doors marked "no admittance"? Was the story set on earth, in space, on another planet? Was the anthology in hard cover, trade paperback, or mass market paperback format? Was it a general anthology or did it have a theme, like "robot stories" or "bratty kid stories"? Did it have interior illustrations?

Answer (score 5):

Just looking at the title instantly gave me the answer because I remember reading it as a child.

It is [Benjamin McFadden and the Robot Babysitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0517799847):

> *When Benjamin's parents go out and leave him in the care of his robot
>   Babysitter, the mischievous boy becomes bored with its rigid ways and
>   reprograms it for "fun." Things get quickly out of hand, and Benjamin
>   is in for more "fun" than he can handle.*

Comment: Outside of the robot babysitter, how does this match the OP's description? (1) Short story in an anthology? (2) The boy was genetically modified? (3) Fighting parents? (4) The babysitter (robot or alien) taught the boy discipline?

Comment: Mischievous boy? The robot tried to teach the boy it was better to go to bed and obey his parents, but Ben reprogrammed the robot because he was super smart.